# Get current index of select on selectize api dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I've been using the Selectize API and struggling on determining how to get the index/position of the currently selected item.

I've looked at the API and found the getValue() to get the value of the selected item but I need the index. I also investigated the .selectize option itself but can't seem to find any attributes that store it?

Answer (score 3):

Using the API, you can use :

```
var selectize = $('#ddowhat').selectize()[0].selectize;

var val = selectize.getValue();
var tag = selectize.getItem(selectize.getValue());
var text = tag.text();
```

If you have multiple options, tag will be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I went about it a little differently - after searching and not finding an answer.

I used jQuery to get all of the selects on the page. Then I looped thru each (so I could change css values for each item individually).

1. **var htmlSelects = $('select');**
2. **htmlSelects.each(function (i) {....}**
3. I got the parent of the select object BEFORE I selectized it:
   **var parentDIV = $(this).closest('div').prop('id');**
4. Then I "selectized" the select object (capturing the z-index of the original so I could change it on dropdown open and revert on close)
   **var $select = _input.selectize({
       options: [{create: true,
                  sortField: 'text'
       }],
       onDropdownOpen: function() {
       var cssZIndex = $('#'+parentDIV).css('zIndex');
           $('#'+parentDIV).attr('cssZIndex', cssZIndex );
           $('#'+parentDIV).css('zIndex', '1000' );
       },
       onDropdownClose: function () {
           $('#'+parentDIV).css('zIndex',$('#'+parentDIV).attr('cssZIndex'));
       }
   });**
5. I used the "partial class match" and the parentDIV to get the selectized dropdown object:
   **var elem = $("[class^='selectize-dropdown']", "#"+parentDIV)[0];**
6. I created a click event action for the selectized select which allowed me to get the textContent attribute of the object ( which holds ALL of the "options" for the selectized select (separated by a newline character )
   $(elem).on('click', '.selectize-dropdown-content div', function(){

   ```
   //GET THE textContent OPTION LIST VALUE,
   //REPLACE THE NEWLINES OR RETURNS WITH A PIPE
   var optionString = $(elem)[0].textContent.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '|');

   //CREATE AN ARRAY OF OPTIONS VALUES
   var optionArray = optionString.split('|');

   //GET THE TEXT VALUE OF THE OPTION CLICKED ON 
   //( AGAIN REPLACE THE NEWLINES OR RETURNS WITH AN EMPTY STRING
   var optionText = $(this).text().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');

   //GET THE INDEX OF THE SELECTED OPTION TEXT VALUE 
   //IN THE OPTIONS LIST ARRAY
   var optionIndex = $.inArray(optionText, optionArray);
   })
   ```